# Formulae of spap2/spapi in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, spline

I need to reconstruct the analytical form of a spline I have calculated with the [spap2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/spap2.html) (or [spapi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/spapi.html)) command, in order to have the `n` polynomials that compose the spline itself, but I don't know the formula in which to put the coefficients stored in the `myspline.coefs` field.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: `spap2` outputs a B-form spline.  You can see how the spline is defined here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/the-b-form.html .  Looking at the link, you can see how an output point is constructed using the information from the B-form spline.

Comment: Thanks, I read it many times before asking but I still don't unterstand how to handle it.

Comment: What about Wikipedia?  It's pretty clear: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Definition

Comment: I read it before posting but I can't find how to use the coefficients stored in the spline struct for retrieving the analytical form of the spline itself.